# Convert UTC string to local datetime string in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I don't have the name of the Time Zone, only have an offset value, like `+0400`.

I have the datetime string in UTC: like `2014-01-07T09:29:35Z`.

I want a string in local time, like `2014-01-07T13:29:35`.

How to do this?

Comment: @Thrustmaster Please read the question which says "I don't have the name for the TimeZone".

Comment: @ATOzTOA Do you have an internet connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to convert string format.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
old_time = '2014-01-07T09:29:35Z'

def time_converter(old_time, time_zone):
    time_zone = float(time_zone[:3] + ('.5' if time_zone[3] == '3' else '.0'))
    str_time = datetime.strptime(old_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    return (str_time + timedelta(hours=time_zone)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for time_zone in ('+0400', '+0430', '-1400'):
        print(time_converter(old_time, time_zone))
```

Output:

```
2014-01-07T13:29:35Z
2014-01-07T13:59:35Z
2014-01-06T19:29:35Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create timezone classes for creating timezone aware datetime objects:

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

class myTimeZone(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=4)
    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=0)

class utcTimeZone(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=0)
    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=0)

d = datetime.strptime("2014-01-07T09:29:35Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").replace(tzinfo=utcTimeZone())
print(d.astimezone(myTimeZone()).isoformat())   # Prints '2014-01-07T13:29:35+04:00'
```